# In response Get single object how i parse according to my requirement

Tags: android, json, coordinates

I get response from Api in this way 
Response is:

```
{"path": "{
    66.933707682325,
    24.876483014725,
    66.943130493164,
    24.862141543725,
    66.943130493164,
    24.862141543725,
    66.885708125774,
    24.7983557697,
    66.652607475339,
    24.774319574644,
    60.05126953125,
    20.842286115167,
    54.684448242188,
    12.567967727957,
    54.569091796875,
    12.329269107613,
    43.26416015625,
    -11.264612212504,
    43.0224609375,
    -11.512322409888,
    41.039428710937,
    -15.400871114077,
    40.294352465028,
    -16.761222134799,
    35.988464355469,
    -23.844140778719,
    35.92529296875,
    -24.837660759535,
    32.71728515625,
    -28.751896559604,
    32.055628740927,
    -29.476657033177,
    31.247484170749,
    -30.365802730651,
    30.399169921875,
    -31.316057884407,
    28.9599609375,
    -32.739519860082,
    27.828564008556,
    -33.525165333088,
    26.724243164062,
    -33.959382290645,
    24.966430664062,
    -34.444054706406,
    19.9951171875,
    -34.946246767964,
    18.314208984375,
    -34.368199449564,
    -47.552828467179,
    -25.776240273816,
    -48.290405273438,
    -25.624192441212,
    -48.33366394043,
    -25.613047870816,
    -48.345336914062,
    -25.546778150624,
    -48.371429443359,
    -25.529430487502,
    -48.398895263672,
    -25.53314805514,
    -48.414688110352,
    -25.542441470125,
    -48.444900512695,
    -25.538104632759,
    -48.472366333008,
    -25.530669689516,
    -48.472366333008,
    -25.530669689516,
    -48.507385253906,
    -25.554053711007
}"
}
```

this is latitude and longitude

I want to draw the polyline on google map in which parameter pass in this way

```
LatLng a = new LatLng(24.876483014725, 66.933707682325);
LatLng a = new LatLng(24.7983557697, 66.885708125774);
LatLng a = new LatLng(24.862141543725, 66.943130493164);
```

So,I parse my response?

Comment: Its not a valid `JSON` you van check here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thats not a proper response  for this type of dataset .. See if you can change the API's response . If you can't then just remove starting and end curly braces and split remaining String with comma ..

Comment: {
 "route": {
  "dist": "15128.73",
  "path": "{66.933707682325,24.876483014725,66.943130493164,24.862141543725774,60.05126953125,20.842286115167,54.684448242188,12.567967727957,54.569091796875,12.329269107613,43.26416015625,-11.264612212504,43.0224609375}",
  "st": 1,
  "port_name_from": "Karachi",
  "port_country_from": "PK",
  "port_name_to": "Paranagua",
  "port_country_to": "BR",
  "locode_from": "PKKHI",
  "locode_to": "BRPNG"
 }
}

Comment: My whole response is this which is valid json

Comment: That path value is a string. You'll have to parse it, then capture every pair of 2 elements

Comment: Thats not a valid `JsonObject` . It can be array if enclose  with `[ ]` instead of `{ }`. So if can not change the response then you can try the split approach i have stated above . which is error prone i guess .

Comment: what format is that supposed to be?

Comment: @Fahad You can upvote my answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **kotlin** you can do something like this:

```
val points: List<LatLng> = JSONObject(data)["path"].toString()
    .replace("{", "")
    .replace("}", "")
    .replace("\n","")
    .replace(" ","")
    .trim()
    .split(",")
    .onEach { it.trim() }
    .chunked(2)
    .map { LatLng(it[0].toDouble(), it[1].toDouble()) }
```

In **Java**:

```
String[] pts = new JSONObject(data).getString("path")
.replace("\n","")
.replace(" ","")
.replace("{","")
.replace("}","")
.split(",");
ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<pts.length;i=i+2){
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(pts[i]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(pts[i+1]);
    list.add(new LatLng(lat,lng));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better that you use a list of a `Double lat` and `Double lng` model to send values from API. And send this list to the drawing function of the line between the geographical points.

if you can't do this. I suggest creating a list of `latlng` model and put even json's cells to `lat` and odd  json's cells to `lng` of the `latlng` model and add it to that list in `for` statement.

**Note :**  get your JSON as string and `string[] latlng= yourJsonString.split[','];` Then you will have access to even and odd cells of the array.

Comment: This doesn't really answer how to parse the data

Comment: It is purchased api which give routes in ocean i am not able to change it